# User feedback from AsyncTask.doInBackground()?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an `AsyncTask` which which takes an `ArrayList` of music files to play. In the `doInBackground` method, I loop through the ArrayList and play the songs one-by-one. I'd like to put a status message on a `TextView` of the UI or something to indicate which song is playing, but getting the error *Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.*  If I only update the UI widgets from `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` the list has already been played. Is there a way to use `onProgressUpdate` or other `AsyncTask` method to do this?

Comment: Could you post your AsyncTask declaration? Not the whole, but just the `public class ... extends AsyncTask` line, and the constructor (if any)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is certainly possible.  Here's a basic example if you had Strings you wanted to display for song name, album name, and artist name (I haven't fully implemented the AsyncTask, just the parts relevant to onProgressUpdate):

```
private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> 
{
     protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) 
     {
         //Get some list of songs, named songs
         for(Song song in songs)//This is the loop where you're playing your songs
         {
             publishProgress(song.name, song.album, song.artist);
             //Play the song and wait for it to finish
         }
         return null;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(String... songData) 
     {
         //Assuming three text views exist to display your data
         nameTextView.setText(songData[0]);
         albumTextView.setText(songData[1]);
         artistTextView.setText(songData[2]);
     }
}
```

The important things to note are the the second class in the angle brackets is the type of parameters for `onProgressUpdate`, and that `publishProgress` gets called in doInBackground to trigger `onProgressUpdate`.  Most examples that you'll find for onProgressUpdate involve increasing the fill on a ProgressBar, but the method runs on the UI thread and can interact with any Views that can be accessed by your AsyncTask.  If you're still having some trouble, post your current AsyncTask so that it'll be easier to help integrate this example class into what you already have. [Here are the docs for AsyncTask for more information.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#)Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use onProgressUpdate() to perform the update from the UI thread. Or, you could do it like this (which is typical when not using AsyncTask).

Post an event on the UI thread that updates your UI like this:

```
view.post( new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Update your UI
    }
});
```

It will be running on the UI thread so it can access and update the view.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is.

When you decalre your AsyncTask, you decalre the types that go into each part of the task:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<URL,Integer,Long> {
.
.
.
}
```

The types in order, for this example:

1. `URL` gets passed to `doInBackground` via `execute`
2. `Integer` gets to `onProgressUpdate` (via `publishProgress`)
3. `Long` gets to `onPostExecute`, also the return value of `doInBackground`

In your `doInBackground()`, you can call `publishProgress()`, which will in turn call `onProgessUpdate()` on the main thread (assuming you created your AsyncTask on the main thread).

There is a complete example in the reference docs under **Usage** ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.htmlhttp://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)).